# Rendering associated ActiveRecord attributes in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, activerecord, view, associations

I'm trying to pull up the names, contact types, and companies associated with a listing, but I'm struggling with rendering then in ActiveRecord. The tables (Contacts, Company, ContactType, join table ListingContacts and Listing) are as follows:

`Contacts.rb`

```
belongs_to :company   #trying to access `name` attribute in view
belongs_to :contact_type   #trying to access `label` attribute in view
```

`Company.rb`

```
 belongs_to :account
 has_many :contacts
```

Accessed through `Listing.rb` using a joined table, `Listing_contacts.rb`:

```
has_many :listing_contacts
has_many :contacts, through: :listing_contacts
```

As accessed through `listings_controller`:

```
def show 
  @listing = Listing.includes(*LISTING_EAGER_LOADED_ASSOCIATIONS).find(params[:id])
end

private 
  def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :address, :description, images_attributes: [:file, :unprocessed_image_url], listing_contacts_attributes: [:contact_id])
  end
```

with `LISTING_EAGER_LOADED_ASSOCIATIONS` as follows (it's a common format in this app, as it gets pretty extensive - I've been avoiding messing with it, and it accesses other models that the ones in the question don't touch:

LISTING_EAGER_LOADED_ASSOCIATIONS = [
      rfid_tags: :trackable, 
      selected_selections: :rfid_tag, 
      staging_selections: :rfid_tag, 
      staged_selections: :rfid_tag, 
      destaged_selections: :rfid_tag,
      unstaged_selections: :rfid_tag,
     ]

**As mentioned earlier, I'm struggling with conveying these associations in the view** - here's what I'm working with, based off of the template from the rest of the page  - accessing listing_contacts is working through the console, but I stall after that:

```
<%= @listing.listing_contacts.each do |contact| -%>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5 class="subtle-header">Name:</h5>
        <h3 class="inline"><%= show(contact.name) %></h3> #working!
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5 class="subtle-header">Address</h5>
        <h3 class="inline"><%= show(contact.address) %></h3> #working!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5 class="subtle-header">Contact Type:</h5>
        <h3 class="inline"><%= show(#reaches through contacts to contact_type.label ) %></h3> #not working
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5 class="subtle-header">Company:</h5>
        <h3 class="inline"><%= show(#reaches through contacts to company.name) %></h3> #not working
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

`structure.sql` for reference - uses SQL views rather than schema;

```
CREATE TABLE public.listing_contacts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    listing_id integer,
    contact_id integer,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.contacts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    company_id integer,
    contact_type_id integer,
    name character varying,
    phone character varying,
    email character varying,
    address text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.companies (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    account_id integer,
    name character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.contact_types (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    label character varying,
    show_name boolean DEFAULT false,
    show_phone boolean DEFAULT false,
    show_address boolean DEFAULT false,
    show_email boolean DEFAULT false,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do <%= @listing.contacts.each do |contact| -%>

And then in your loop, you should be able to do `<%= show(contact.name) %>`

Comment: That works for directly accessing contacts (name, address); what about reaching through contacts to the `contact_type` and `company` tables? Sorry, I left those blank in the view since I thought the question was clear enough at the time - fixed.

Comment: After updating the `.each` loop as mentioned above, you should be able to `<%= show(contact.contact_type.label)%>` and <%= show(contact.company.name)%>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<%= lc.contacts.name %>` instead of `<%= show(lc.contacts.name) %>` ?

Comment: Its an application helper method. Please ignore.